# What are the security implications of receiving a Paypal app ID from the server?

Tags: security, mobile, paypal

I'm using the paypal mobile SDK. Currently, I store the app ID on the client, but there is a feature request to receive the app ID dynamically from a server (via https).

I'm wondering, are there any security implications to this approach that I should consider before going ahead?

I mean, a capable hacker could get to the app ID within the application code in any case, I assume. And we will send the app ID encrypted in https.

Plus, what would anyone do with the app id once they get a hold of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not much; the app ID is linked to your API user as far as I know. I'd suggest double-checking with PayPal themselves, but as far as I know it shouldn't be a problem.